# Is there a way to update playground openai.api_version?

Tags: azure, azure-openai

I have deployed the latest `gpt-35-turbo` model, with model version '0613', however, when I tried to test it in chat playground, I realized that `openai.api_version` remains "2023-03-15-preview", and I could not find a way to update it to the latest version. Tried every region still no luck.

## Test step:

1. Deployed a `gpt-35-turbo` chat model with model version `0613`

[image]

2. Tried to test it in playground.

[image]

3. Select View code section to check the parameter.

[image]

4. `openai.api_version` remains "2023-03-15-preview"

[image]

5. Tried different regions with same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

`Model version` is not `api-version`. These configure two different things.

### Long answer

OpenAI Model is not accessed directly, but rather through a middleman (Azure API):

```
You -> Azure API -> OpenAI Model
```

Both the API and the Model have versioning:

**Model Version** is for the AI Model by OpenAI. A new version usually means that the model is retrained with the latest data. In your example, the `gpt-35-turbo` model has version `0613`.

**API Version** is for the Azure API ([read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/reference)). A new version may introduce new capabilities (such as [embeddings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/reference#embeddings)) or make old capabilities unavailable.